# How to make center of BorderLayout the top

Tags: java, awt, layout-manager, border-layout

I have a `BorderLayout`, and the main content is in the center. However, I have some content at the bottom corners, and it is overlapping the main content, even though there is no content there. Is there a way to make the center so it would overlap instead?

[image]

The main text cuts off at the same point the curl begins.

```
private void prepareGUI() throws IOException {

        mainFrame = new JFrame("Holy Bible");
        mainFrame.setSize(700, 500);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/assets/bible/textures/icon.png")).getImage());
        mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        mainFrame.addKeyListener(this);

        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        leftLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        leftLabel.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 12));
        centerPanel.add(leftLabel);

        rightLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        rightLabel.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 12));
        centerPanel.add(rightLabel);

        leftCurl = new JLabel();
        leftCurl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        leftCurl.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        leftCurl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/assets/bible/textures/curlleft15.png")));
        mainFrame.add(leftCurl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        rightCurl = new JLabel();
        rightCurl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
        rightCurl.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        rightCurl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/assets/bible/textures/curlright15.png")));
        mainFrame.add(rightCurl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainFrame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // Maximizes frame
        mainFrame.setUndecorated(fullScreen);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

This is the code that prepares the GUI. The text is added in a separate method.

Comment: `"I have some content at the bottom corners, and it is overlapping the main content, even though there is no content there."` -- how can it overlap content when there is no content?? Please avoid confusing posts like this. Show code and pictures, and try to be more clear in your descriptions. For code, preferably post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The only reason it will overlap is if you've been adding more components to the `CENTER` position of the `BorderLayout`. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2):

You will likely need to nest JPanels and layouts to achieve your goal. For instance, two JPanels that use BorderLayout could help here with the main JPanel using BorderLayout, adding the text to the CENTER position. Then adding another JPanel that uses BorderLayout to the main JPanel's EAST or LINE_END position. Place your page curl at the BorderLayout.PAGE_END or SOUTH position of the second JPanel.